# why does logger.info output only 6 lines?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j

My project is based on spring-boot framework. The following are the configuration in logback-spring.xml

```
    <appender name="defaultLogFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${system.log.path}/${appName}-default.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${system.log.path}/${appName}-default.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} Method:%M Line:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The following are the logger code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        logger.info("asdfasdfsadf i = {}", i);

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("dddddd");
        }
    }
```

The following are the output of logger info.

```
2018-05-16 09:18:16,164 [main] INFO  c.x.********.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 0
2018-05-16 09:18:16.164  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 0
2018-05-16 09:18:18,169 [main] INFO  c.x.*******.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 1
2018-05-16 09:18:18.169  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 1
2018-05-16 09:18:20,172 [main] INFO  c.x.*******.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 2
2018-05-16 09:18:20.172  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 2
2018-05-16 09:18:22,176 [main] INFO  c.x.*******.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 3
2018-05-16 09:18:22.176  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 3
2018-05-16 09:18:24,181 [main] INFO  c.x.*******.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 4
2018-05-16 09:18:24.181  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 4
2018-05-16 09:18:26,184 [main] INFO  c.x.*******.RecommendationTest 
Method:test Line:58 - asdfasdfsadf i = 5
2018-05-16 09:18:26.184  INFO 1399 --- [           main] 
com.*******.RecommendationTest  : asdfasdfsadf i = 5
```

Only 6 lines, Why? Any suggestions or advices are welcome.

Comment: Move `logger.info("asdfasdfsadf i = {}", i);` into the `try` block. This will catch any exceptions it may be throwing since I am not readily seeing any issues with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My project needs to record some running information besides exceptions. So many logger.info are not in the  try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste code you have written in your application.properties to include this logback.xml?
Looking at your logback file it seems that you are generating day wise backup file.
There might be a chance of getting exception so please add logger.info in catch instead of SOP, hope it gives some hint.
Please try running the code removing  code from logback.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My project needs to record some running information besides exceptions. So many logger.info are not in the  try catch block.

Comment: Just to test if any exception we get while running the code, so we need to write one info line in catch block. Everything seems ok in logback.xml